# numpy.mean precision for large arrays

Tags: numpy, precision

I do not understand why casting a float32-Array to a float64-Array changes the mean of the array significantly.

```
import numpy as n  

a = n.float32(100. * n.random.random_sample((10000000))+1000.)
b = a.astype(n.float64)        
print n.mean(a), a.dtype, a.shape
print n.mean(b), b.dtype, b.shape
```

result (should be approx. 1050, so float64 is correct):

```
1028.346368   float32 (10000000,)                                                          
1049.98284473 float64 (10000000,)
```

Answer (score 6):

@bogatron has explained what causes the loss in precision. To get around this kind of problem, `np.mean` has an optional `dtype` argument, that lets you specify what type to use for the internal operations. So you can do:

```
>>> np.mean(a)
1028.3446272000001
>>> np.mean(a.astype(np.float64))
1049.9776601123901
>>> np.mean(a, dtype=np.float64)
1049.9776601123901
```

The third case is significantly faster than the second, although slower than the first:

```
In [3]: %timeit np.mean(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.mean(a.astype(np.float64))
10 loops, best of 3: 51 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit np.mean(a, dtype=np.float64)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

32-bit floating point numbers are only accurate to about 7 significant digits.  As the sum of your values grows, you start losing the accuracy of smaller digits.  64-bit numbers have somewhere around 13-16 significant so you would require much larger sums to see the same effect.

To see this effect on your example, notice the means for growing subsets of the arrays:

```
>>> for i in [j * 1000000 for j in range(1, 11)]:
...   print i, n.mean(a[:i]), n.mean(b[:i])
... 
1000000  1050.92768    1049.95339668
2000000  1045.289856   1049.96298122
3000000  1038.47466667 1049.97903538
4000000  1034.856      1049.98635745
5000000  1032.6848512  1049.98521094
6000000  1031.237376   1049.98658562
7000000  1030.20346514 1049.98757511
8000000  1029.428032   1049.98615102
9000000  1028.82497422 1049.98925409
10000000 1028.3424768  1049.98771529
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the implementation of mean and sum functions.

Float values have constant precision. When you add small value to some large one, you lose the precision of the small value.

To overcome the problem you need to divide the array and partialy compute the sum:

```
s=n.float32(0)
for p in xrange(0,a.size,1000):
    s+= n.sum(a[p:p+1000])
print 'Sum:',s
print 'Mean:',s/a.size
```

Will give you more correct result.

Comment: In [this article](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr222.pdf), in page 2, right after formula (1.6) they describe what they call the _pairwise summation algorithm_, similar what your solution presents, and describe how it reduces rounding error from O(N) to O(log N).